# Style every single tab of a QTabWidget differently from each other

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have a `QTabWidget` that contains 4 tabs. I would like to style each header of them individually : I saw I could use stylesheet to possibly do that. But my problem is that I couldn't just change the header of one tab, where the name of the tab is, without changing the rest of the tab.

In a simple way, imagine I want to have the first tab red, the second blue, 3rd green and the 4th yellow. So, how can I change the style of every single tab without changing the others.

Thanks!

EDIT

I saw [there](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar) how I could change the style of all tab headers at once, but not individually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you subclass QTabWidget, you can access the protected function `QTabWidget::tabBar()`, which returns the QTabBar it uses. QTabBar has a method `QTabBar::setTabTextColor()` that will change the text color of an individual tab. Here is an example:

```
#include <QtGui>

class TabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
public:
    TabWidget()
    {
        addTab(new QPushButton("Hi 1!"), "Button 1 Tab");
        addTab(new QPushButton("Hi 2!"), "Button 2 Tab");
        tabBar()->setTabTextColor(0, QColor(Qt::red));
        tabBar()->setTabTextColor(1, QColor(Qt::blue));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    TabWidget tabWidget;

    tabWidget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

If you need more control, you can make your own tab widget. According to the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#details), QTabWidget is basically just a QStackedWidget combined with a QTabBar. You can make your own tab widget by combining a QStackedWidget with, for example, a set of stylized QPushButtons.

Comment: thanks for that! that's kind of what I want...but I would like to change the background of the tab's header instead of the text because I have a styled one for each...I tried to look in the document as deep as I could but I didn't see anything for that. I looked for making my own tabwidget, but even with that, I didn't see how I could change the background of a tab in the tab bar

Comment: @castors33 If you must change the background, I recommend making your own widget by combining QStackedWidget and some QPushButtons, perhaps in a QToolBar. Of course, you could try subclassing QTabWidget and reimplementing `paintEvent`, but I have a feeling that would get annoyingly complicated. Either way, it seems that style sheets won't work for accessing individual tab headers. You could easily style buttons individually, though.

Comment: ok...that seems a bit long but looks ok. I'm going to try this thanks!